# Wired internet works for few seconds on Debian

Tags: debian, networking

I recently changed my isp, and after that I started having some issues when connecting to the internet on my Debian 10. At first, I thought that it might be my ISPs fault, but the internet is working fine on Windows (Ive dual boot) and on my phone (wifi). On Debian, the internet works for few seconds, enought to load 1 page, but after that doesnt work anymore. I already tried to increase MTUs value, since looked like it helped others who had this problem, but didn't work for me. Also, i tested using my Laptop, which also has Debian 10 installed, it worked. I tested using cable and wifi.

**dmesg | tail -20** gives me:

```
[   13.976571] br-a16997434552: port 1(veth6622e95) entered forwarding state
[   13.976619] eth0: renamed from vethdb50e9c
[   13.996186] eth0: renamed from vethcbb270b
[   14.044342] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): br-a16997434552: link becomes ready
[   14.044712] eth0: renamed from veth6bc5a88
[   14.068466] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth94bcb37: link becomes ready
[   14.068523] br-bcf7ce342cb9: port 1(veth94bcb37) entered blocking state
[   14.068527] br-bcf7ce342cb9: port 1(veth94bcb37) entered forwarding state
[   14.068614] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vetha3f8b80: link becomes ready
[   14.068658] br-f68c9df397fa: port 1(vetha3f8b80) entered blocking state
[   14.068661] br-f68c9df397fa: port 1(vetha3f8b80) entered forwarding state
[   14.068758] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): br-bcf7ce342cb9: link becomes ready
[   14.068836] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): br-f68c9df397fa: link becomes ready
[   14.069028] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vetha784882: link becomes ready
[   14.069063] br-37692a4e723c: port 1(vetha784882) entered blocking state
[   14.069065] br-37692a4e723c: port 1(vetha784882) entered forwarding state
[   14.069117] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): br-37692a4e723c: link becomes ready
[   14.121290] r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control off
[   19.920051] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 20
[   20.224017] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D0: HDMI: invalid ELD data byte 20
```

**wget http://www.duckduckgo.com** gives me:

```
--2021-05-30 00:12:43--  http://www.duckduckgo.com/
Resolvendo www.duckduckgo.com (www.duckduckgo.com)... 191.235.123.80
Conectando-se a www.duckduckgo.com (www.duckduckgo.com)|191.235.123.80|:80... falhou: Tempo esgotado para conexão.
Tentando novamente.

--2021-05-30 00:13:23--  (tentativa: 2)  http://www.duckduckgo.com/
Conectando-se a www.duckduckgo.com (www.duckduckgo.com)|191.235.123.80|:80... falhou: Tempo esgotado para conexão.
Tentando novamente.

--2021-05-30 00:13:57--  (tentativa: 3)  http://www.duckduckgo.com/
Conectando-se a www.duckduckgo.com (www.duckduckgo.com)|191.235.123.80|:80... falhou: Tempo esgotado para conexão.
Tentando novamente.

--2021-05-30 00:14:31--  (tentativa: 4)  http://www.duckduckgo.com/
Conectando-se a www.duckduckgo.com (www.duckduckgo.com)|191.235.123.80|:80... ^C
```

**ip route get 1.1.1.1** gives me:

```
1.1.1.1 via 192.168.0.1 dev enp3s0 src 192.168.0.102 uid 1000 
    cache
```

**ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route** gives me:

```
lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> 
enp3s0           UP             18:31:bf:b3:38:7d <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
br-9ca719aa01c7  DOWN           02:42:97:ea:72:b0 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-b97158ffcc3c  DOWN           02:42:74:c5:64:57 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
docker0          DOWN           02:42:c9:ef:9e:71 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-55cb011b3e0d  DOWN           02:42:04:1a:72:0a <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-777211ddb717  DOWN           02:42:4f:08:86:92 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-a16997434552  UP             02:42:55:72:e0:b8 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
br-bcf7ce342cb9  UP             02:42:f1:f0:8e:7b <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
br-d4e258cd683a  DOWN           02:42:05:9b:2d:27 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-4b3e4deacee9  DOWN           02:42:9d:07:40:5b <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-f68c9df397fa  UP             02:42:92:59:d5:6c <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
br-131ad989692b  DOWN           02:42:84:4e:6e:12 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-194e7a613502  DOWN           02:42:61:b8:5d:7a <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-2a67d8f8b954  DOWN           02:42:c2:d1:b4:e1 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-37692a4e723c  UP             02:42:a9:7b:1f:3a <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
br-3f32a31d3339  UP             02:42:06:e1:4b:19 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
br-499e90637a6b  DOWN           02:42:3c:d7:50:ca <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-552074ecc891  DOWN           02:42:f8:04:ed:b7 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-0e204ce773a5  DOWN           02:42:a5:2c:56:25 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-68d74d345015  DOWN           02:42:42:d7:7a:37 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-c41dfb61e164  DOWN           02:42:ee:61:a9:ae <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-cf71a6f7b6d3  DOWN           02:42:52:85:a0:b7 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-f0c082f01e56  DOWN           02:42:d3:80:d0:bf <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
br-639bfb1bea34  DOWN           02:42:2f:93:cc:d2 <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> 
veth759ec1c@if26 UP             2e:8a:16:fd:f5:de <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
veth44148ca@if28 UP             62:b4:1f:13:bc:51 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
vethc7f2d65@if30 UP             52:9e:00:cb:c7:46 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
veth0067bf4@if32 UP             5e:6f:bb:a0:28:1c <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
veth443e622@if34 UP             d2:97:46:de:79:91 <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> 
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
enp3s0           UP             192.168.0.102/24 2804:14c:6583:5e7f::1000/128 2804:14c:6583:5e7f:c496:f510:ca8c:79ce/64 fe80::9847:c342:d509:4024/64 
br-9ca719aa01c7  DOWN           192.168.96.1/20 
br-b97158ffcc3c  DOWN           172.20.0.1/16 
docker0          DOWN           172.17.0.1/16 
br-55cb011b3e0d  DOWN           192.168.160.1/20 
br-777211ddb717  DOWN           172.26.0.1/16 
br-a16997434552  UP             172.28.0.1/16 fe80::42:55ff:fe72:e0b8/64 
br-bcf7ce342cb9  UP             172.22.0.1/16 fe80::42:f1ff:fef0:8e7b/64 
br-d4e258cd683a  DOWN           172.24.0.1/16 
br-4b3e4deacee9  DOWN           192.168.48.1/20 
br-f68c9df397fa  UP             172.27.0.1/16 fe80::42:92ff:fe59:d56c/64 
br-131ad989692b  DOWN           172.23.0.1/16 
br-194e7a613502  DOWN           192.168.80.1/20 
br-2a67d8f8b954  DOWN           192.168.240.1/20 
br-37692a4e723c  UP             172.29.0.1/16 fe80::42:a9ff:fe7b:1f3a/64 
br-3f32a31d3339  UP             172.31.0.1/16 fe80::42:6ff:fee1:4b19/64 
br-499e90637a6b  DOWN           172.18.0.1/16 
br-552074ecc891  DOWN           172.19.0.1/16 
br-0e204ce773a5  DOWN           172.30.0.1/16 
br-68d74d345015  DOWN           192.168.16.1/20 
br-c41dfb61e164  DOWN           192.168.0.1/20 
br-cf71a6f7b6d3  DOWN           172.25.0.1/16 
br-f0c082f01e56  DOWN           172.21.0.1/16 
br-639bfb1bea34  DOWN           192.168.112.1/20 
veth759ec1c@if26 UP             fe80::2c8a:16ff:fefd:f5de/64

Lucas Andrade, [30.05.21 09:50]
veth44148ca@if28 UP             fe80::60b4:1fff:fe13:bc51/64 
vethc7f2d65@if30 UP             fe80::509e:ff:fecb:c746/64 
veth0067bf4@if32 UP             fe80::5c6f:bbff:fea0:281c/64 
veth443e622@if34 UP             fe80::d097:46ff:fede:7991/64 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-499e90637a6b proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
172.19.0.0/16 dev br-552074ecc891 proto kernel scope link src 172.19.0.1 linkdown 
172.20.0.0/16 dev br-b97158ffcc3c proto kernel scope link src 172.20.0.1 linkdown 
172.21.0.0/16 dev br-f0c082f01e56 proto kernel scope link src 172.21.0.1 linkdown 
172.22.0.0/16 dev br-bcf7ce342cb9 proto kernel scope link src 172.22.0.1 
172.23.0.0/16 dev br-131ad989692b proto kernel scope link src 172.23.0.1 linkdown 
172.24.0.0/16 dev br-d4e258cd683a proto kernel scope link src 172.24.0.1 linkdown 
172.25.0.0/16 dev br-cf71a6f7b6d3 proto kernel scope link src 172.25.0.1 linkdown 
172.26.0.0/16 dev br-777211ddb717 proto kernel scope link src 172.26.0.1 linkdown 
172.27.0.0/16 dev br-f68c9df397fa proto kernel scope link src 172.27.0.1 
172.28.0.0/16 dev br-a16997434552 proto kernel scope link src 172.28.0.1 
172.29.0.0/16 dev br-37692a4e723c proto kernel scope link src 172.29.0.1 
172.30.0.0/16 dev br-0e204ce773a5 proto kernel scope link src 172.30.0.1 linkdown 
172.31.0.0/16 dev br-3f32a31d3339 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.0.1 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.102 metric 100 
192.168.0.0/20 dev br-c41dfb61e164 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.16.0/20 dev br-68d74d345015 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.16.1 linkdown 
192.168.48.0/20 dev br-4b3e4deacee9 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.48.1 linkdown 
192.168.80.0/20 dev br-194e7a613502 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.80.1 linkdown 
192.168.96.0/20 dev br-9ca719aa01c7 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.96.1 linkdown 
192.168.112.0/20 dev br-639bfb1bea34 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.112.1 linkdown 
192.168.160.0/20 dev br-55cb011b3e0d proto kernel scope link src 192.168.160.1 linkdown 
192.168.240.0/20 dev br-2a67d8f8b954 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.240.1 linkdown
```

Comment: Can you share the dmesg output from around the time the problem manifests?

Comment: @Panos hi, do you want the full output of `sudo dmesg`? Or should i use some specific parameter? thanks in advance

Comment: Did you set a firewall? Are you using ipv6? Do you have an idea of a previous change that might be related to networking?

Comment: No, I didn't make any changes on Debian. I'm pretty sure that I'm using ipv4.

Comment: I don't know if it is relevant, but right now I'm using the internet. But to make it work, I had to route the internet from my phone (wifi) to my computer, through usb.

Comment: As soon as your internet stops, do a `dmesg | tail -20` and please share it with us. Also, please add the ouput from `wget http://www.duckduckgo.com` because you might have lost connectivity or name resolution and both manifest as *internet does not work*.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani just added it. Sorry for the output of wget being in portuguese. But briefly it gave me an timeout 4x

Comment: You seem to have name resolution working, which in turn means that you have connectivity (most likely a `ping 1.1.1.1` will be succesful). You are also using ipv4. A timeout like this is usually tied to some kind of traffic blocking, it could be a firewall on that Debian box, or the router blocking that specific workstation for some reason. (by the way, if you do a `LANG=C wget ...` the output will be in English.)

Comment: I just ran `ping 1.1.1.1` and i got this: `PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
219 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 451ms
`

Comment: What are these br- interfaces? This counts as "previous changes that might be related to networking". Are you running Docker? That would explain.  Can you add the results of  `ip route get 1.1.1.1` + `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route` to get information on your network settings? Then try and disable Docker: `systemctl disable --now docker`, then reboot (to get rid of all network changes).

Comment: @A.B sorry, i didnt mention docker because I was using it since january, on my previous ISP, and it was working fine. When you asked me about previous changes I imagined that you're asking about recent changes. I add the outputs. The internet is working after `systemctl disable --now docker`, but why was docker's fault?

Comment: The entry with 192.168.0.0/20 sets 192.168.0.1 as a local address. It's also the gateway address: conflict.

Answer (score 1):

OP actually had a *lot* of network settings: several Docker networks.

One of them, shown here:

address:

> ```
> br-c41dfb61e164  DOWN           192.168.0.1/20
> ```

route:

> ```
> 192.168.0.0/20 dev br-c41dfb61e164 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.1 linkdown
> ```

adds a new address to the host: 192.168.0.1/20. As Linux follows the Weak [Host Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_model), this address is always available (with *lo* up) whatever the state of *br-c41dfb61e164*.

It conflicts with the DHCP settings set by the host's router (aka gateway), which uses 192.168.0.1/24. DHCP on Linux uses out-of-band methods (raw sockets) to work, so bypasses any network "anomaly": while DHCP works, it then sets:

> ```
> default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp metric 100
> ```

When an host has its own address as gateway, it's as if it didn't use any gateway: any request for any address on Internet will trigger an ARP request which will fail instead of sending packets through the router (which would be the only address for which an ARP would have been made with correct network settings). Beside, this could also randomly disrupt other devices using this network because it would also answer ARP requests for the gateway address.

The quick fix is to disable and stop Docker and maybe reboot if things weren't cleaned up properly, as [OP confirmed in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651998/wired-internet-works-for-few-seconds-on-debian?noredirect=1#comment1223938_651998):

```
systemctl disable --now docker
```

(which could optionally also be associated with `systemctl mask docker.socket` to avoid any "spurious" start)

The long term fix is about Docker settings and would be out of the scope of this question. Here are a two suggestions:

- clean up unused containers and associated networks
- change Docker settings so allocations of new networks are smaller (eg /24) and in an unused address space, possible somewhere in the 10.0.0.0/8 but then beware of clash with some VPNs.

  example can be taken from this SF Q/A: [Configuring Docker to not use the 172.17.0.0 range](https://serverfault.com/questions/916941/configuring-docker-to-not-use-the-172-17-0-0-range)